# how to convert data to collection list from dataSnapshot, in Android FirebaseDatabase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I  am getting list of data from firebase database using addValueEventListener, I got the data in dataSnapshot and I can call getValue to get the data, but is there any way I can directly convert it to Arraylist 
Right now I am doing like this

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot matchSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Match match = matchSnapShot.getValue(Match.class);
        matchList.add(match);
    }
    Object obj= dataSnapshot.getValue();
    Toast.makeText(NewMatchActivity.this,"got data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

but I want some thing like this

```
ArrayList<Match> matchList = dataSnapshot.getValue(ArrayList<Match.class>);
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on your exact data structure (a representable snippet of the JSON as text would help for that), but most likely the data you are getting back is a Map and not a List.

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Map<String,Match> map = (Map<String, Match>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    Collection<Match> matches = map.values();
}
```

Comment: I try this but matches is collection of HashMap not a collection of Match class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
GenericTypeIndicator<List<Match>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<Match>>(){};
List<Match> matchList = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
```

Comment: I am getting this exception"Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap"